# Angular2 base64 encode image doesnt exist

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using jspdf with angular2 cli and I would like to add an image.

I have tried

```
let doc = new JSPdf();
let imgData ='data:image/jpeg;base64,'+Base64.encode('/assets/images/reportimg.jpg');
doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 15, 40, 180, 180);
doc.save('reports.pdf');
```

The image is located in assets/images directory

I have also tried

```
 let imgData ='data:image/jpeg;base64,'+Base64.encode('assets/images/reportimg.jpg');
 doc.addImage(imgData, 'jpg', 15, 40, 180, 180);
doc.save('reports.pdf');
```

I am getting an error:

```
ERROR Error: Supplied data is not a JPEG
at getJpegSizeFromBytes
```

What could be wrong yet the image is a jpg?

Comment: Is this code in one of the components inside app?

Comment: yes its inside the component

Comment: Check the path of your image, the problem is there most probably

Comment: ive tried including an imnage from the internet like: https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/p/2/005/076/082/230d6eb.jpg but still get the same error

Comment: The assets path has to be relative. E.g. `../assets/path/to/your/image.jpg`

Comment: still fails to work

Comment: create a plunker if possible, here is a template: https://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:AvJOMERrnz94ekVua0u5

Comment: check  https://plnkr.co/edit/qyt9oPyfIZ9tvwMofdoU?p=preview though through plunker i havent been able to include the base64 package